# Dropbox selective sync with external software

Tags: synchronization, dropbox

I need to choose what folder to sync with dropbox from an external software (java for example). With the dropbox application thats easy using the selective sync option but I cant find a way to do it without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a Java SDK.  [Here's](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=46501&replies=32) is the latest version of their API

You could also post the question at the API forum [here](http://forums.dropbox.com/forum.php?id=5) but I haven't seen any selective sync methods other than in the native client.

more API [reference](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#request-token) here